# Sidekiq/Redis queuing a job that doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, cron, sidekiq, sidekiq-cron

I built a simple test job for Sidekiq and added it to my `schedule.yml` file for Sidekiq Cron.

Here's my test job:

```
module Slack
  class TestJob < ApplicationJob
    queue_as :default

    def perform(*args)
      begin
        SLACK_NOTIFIER.post(attachments: {"pretext": "test", "text": "hello"})
      rescue Exception => error
        puts error
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The `SLACK_NOTIFIER` here is a simple API client for Slack that I initialize on startup.

And in my `schedule.yml`:

```
test_job:
  cron: "* * * * *"
  class: "Slack::TestJob"
  queue: default
  description: "Test"
```

So I wanted to have it run every minute, and it worked exactly as I expected.

However, I've now deleted the job file and removed the job from `schedule.yml`, and it still tries to run the job every minute. I've gone into my sidekiq dashboard, and I see a bunch of retries for that job. No matter how many times I kill them all, they just keep coming.

I've tried shutting down both the redis server and sidekiq several times. I've tried turning off my computer (after killing the servers, of course). It still keeps scheduling these jobs and it's interrupting my other jobs because it raises the following exception:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Slack::TestJob
```

I've done a project-wide search for "TestJob", but get no results.

I only had the redis server open with this job for roughly 10 minutes...

Is there maybe something lingering in the redis database? I've looked into the `redis-cli` documentation, but I don't think any of it helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `$ FLUSHALL` in the redis cli...

Other than that...

The [sidekiq-cron documentation](https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron#active-job-worker) seems to expect that you check for the existence of `schedule.yml` explicitly...

```
#initializers/sidekiq.rb
schedule_file = "config/schedule.yml"

if File.exist?(schedule_file) && Sidekiq.server?
  Sidekiq::Cron::Job.load_from_hash YAML.load_file(schedule_file)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The default for Sidekiq is to [retry a failed job 25 times](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling). Because the job doesn't exist, it fails... every time; Sidekiq only knows that the job fails (because attempting to perform a job that doesn't exist would raise an exception), so it flags it for retry... 25 times. Because you were scheduling that job every minute, you probably had a TON of these failed jobs queued up for retry. You can:

- Wait ~3 weeks to hit the maximum number of retries
- If you have a UI page set up for Sidekiq, you can see and clear these jobs in the Retries tab
- Dig through the Redis CLI documentation for a way to identify these specific jobs and delete them (or flush the whole thing if you're not worried about losing other jobs)